# .htaccess unnecessary Pinterest arrays redirection to actual URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How Can I redirect this pattern

`example.com/fruits/7285/good-slug","id":"33b4","favicon_link":"https:/i.pinimg.com/fa/9.png`

to this:

```
example.com/fruits/7285/good-slug
```

Tried:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(fruits/\d+/[\w-]+). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

But it redirects too much.

Pinterest referring such URL(**abc.com/fruits/123/slug**) by adding some arrays after my URL, I do not know how, so I need to redirect to my actual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule with a [**possessive quantifier**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```sh
RewriteRule ^(fruits/\d+/[\w-]++). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

`[\w-]++` matches longest possible string matching a word or hyphen characters without any backtracking.

On the other hand `^(fruits/\d+/[\w-]+).` will cause a redirect loop because regex engine backtracks to allow a match of a single character after `[\w-]+` pattern.